# MikroTik показывает router.lan или IP

Tags: mikrotik

MikroTik показывает имя router.lan или IP адрес самого роутера когда пользователь подключился к серверу. **Как сделать так чтобы показывал реальный IP адрес или имя пользователя который подключился к серверу а не MikroTik?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К какому серверу, причем тут микротик?

Comment: смотря как вы пробрасываете пользователей к серверу. Если просто dst-nat то должно быть прозрачно, а если еще и src-nat то не должно быть видно.

Comment: @dash1121 Пробрасываю через chain: dstnat, protokol: 6 (tcp), port 3050, action: dst-nat. Добавил скрин подключения

Comment: схему сети покажите